# Unity 3D RotateTowards not working need a threshold I think

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code that rotates an object towards a target point at a smooth rate.

```
public bool RotatedTowards(Vector3 lookAtPoint, float deltaTime)
{
    flatDirPath = Vector3.Scale((lookAtPoint - transform.position), new Vector3(1, 0, 1));
    targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(flatDirPath, Vector3.up);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, deltaTime * basicProperties.turnRate);
    if (Vector3.Dot(flatDirPath.normalized, transform.forward) >= 0.9f)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }        
}
```

It works well enough, the problem is if I right click around a point to move to really fast (telling this object to rotate toward a very similar but different lookAtPoint at a very high frequency), the object shakes very slightly as its constantly making small rotational changes (I believe that's whats happening).

I believe the best solution may be to only do the transform.rotation if the target point is over a threshold from the front of the object, say at least 1 degree to the left or the right of the direction the object is already facing. How could I test this? If it's under 1 degree, no point rotating toward it, and that should remove the shaking from clicking around the same point really fast. I hope.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Just a general comment: you should substitute your entire last `if` block into just `return Vector3.Dot(flatDirPath.normalized, transform.forward) >= 0.9f`

Comment: yes that would be more efficient thanks. Btw I've tried using Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, flatDirPath.normalized) and it doesnt work, _ get really inconsistent results with basically the same spot sometimes 0.05 degrees sometimes 178 degrees sometimes 10 degrees

Answer (score 1):

you can use this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Angle.html

in your code:

```
public bool RotatedTowards(Vector3 lookAtPoint, float deltaTime)
{
    flatDirPath = Vector3.Scale((lookAtPoint - transform.position), new Vector3(1, 0, 1));
    targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(flatDirPath, Vector3.up);

    float angle = Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, targetRotation);
    float threshold = 1;

    if(Mathf.Abs(angle) > threshold)
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, deltaTime * basicProperties.turnRate);

    return (Vector3.Dot(flatDirPath.normalized, transform.forward) >= 0.9f);       
}
```

if you don't like how this threshold behaves, you can try another approach:

use `Queue<Vector3>` to store the last few `flatDirPath` vectors (last 10, for example), then add a new vector each time and remove the oldest vector each time - then compute the average vector from all vectors in the Queue and use that in `Quaternion.LookRotation` - you should get a more smooth behavior. the rotation will lag behind a bit with more vectors you store in the Queue, so use 4-6 vectors for a faster response or 10-20 vectors for a more smooth response.

Comment: Old thread, I'll try my luck nonetheless. Do you actually need to check `Mathf.Abs(angle) > threshold`? The doc specifies "but note that the rotation will not overshoot"

Comment: @Someprogammer You can try without it, but the OP specifically requested a threshold :)